# CAS Policy error in C++ while executing the EXE windows service

Tags: c++, powershell, windows-services

> This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by
>   the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility
>   reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration
>   switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for
>   more information.

This is the error I am facing

I am trying to access my EXE file to install the file but it is throwing such error. Here are details

```
"$progExe"                    #AmsoPana\AMSOService.exe
"$dir"                        #AmsoPana
"$userServiceName"            #AMSOService
"$requiresInstanceNameSwitch" #true
"$displayName"                #CompanyName PANA Service


if($displayName -eq $null)
       {
         .\Tools\Deployment.exe type="exec" program="C:\CompanyName\CPANA\$progExe" directory="C:\xys\CPANA\$dir" param="/install ${Instance_Name_Arg} /SERVICENAME $userServiceName"  serviceNotExists="$userServiceName"  
       }
else
       {
          .\Tools\Deployment.exe type="exec" program="C:\CompanyName\CPANA\$progExe" directory="C:\xyz\CPANA\$dir" param="/install ${Instance_Name_Arg} /SERVICENAME $userServiceName /DISPLAYNAME &quot;$displayName&quot;"  serviceNotExists="$userServiceName"
       }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact text of the _error message_ as well as the code that is throwing it.

Comment: I'm missing the C++ code. And the .Net Framework suggests that there's managed code involved, whereas C++ compiles to native code.